# Не записывается в Map все значения

Tags: java, циклы, коллекции, hashmap

Здравствуйте! Не могу понять что не так

```
NavigableMap map_all = new TreeMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
  map_all.put(i, j); //1
 }
}
System.out.println("map_all : " + map_all);
```

Смешной пример, но результат

```
map_all : {0=0, 1=0, 2=0, 3=0, 4=0, 5=0, 6=0, 7=0, 8=0, 9=0}
```

а хотелось

```
map_all : {0=0, 0=1, 0=2, 0=3, 0=4, 0=5, 0=6, 0=7, 0=8, 0=9 ... 9=0, 9=1, 9=2, 9=3, 9=4, 9=5, 9=6, 9=7, 9=8, 9=9}
```

при записи он в //1 перезаписывает значение. Растолкуйте пожалуйста.

p.s. я же не сошел с ума(

Comment: Ключи не могут повторяться.

Comment: Если бы было так, как вам хочется, то что должно было бы вернутся при вызове map_all.get(0)?

Comment: спасибо, я понял) не могу ответить на Ваш вопрос, стыдно признать...